# Knight's tours in higher dimensions

Tags: discrete-geometry, recreational-mathematics, chess, hamiltonian-graphs

I wonder if [Knight's Tours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) have been explored in higher dimensions,
using the following definition of a knight move.

- In dimension $d=2$, the knight moves left/right and forward/back
  one step and two steps in either order. So $\{ \pm 1, \pm 2 \}$ steps. This leads to $8$ moves.
- In dimension $d=3$, the knight moves
  $\{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \}$ steps in any order along
  $x,y,z$ axes.
  This leads to $48$ moves; see below.
- In dimension $d$, the knight moves $\{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots \pm d \}$
  steps in any order along the axes.
  This leads to $d!\, 2^d$ moves.

I have found literature on knight's tours in 3D but under a different (planar)
definition of move.<sup>1</sup>

It would be interesting to learn which (if any!) $n \times n \times n$
cube chess boards allow a knight's tour.

[image: KnightMoves3D]

<sup>1</sup>
Awani Kumar.
"Magic Knight's Tours in Higher Dimensions." ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0458))

---

**Addendum**. *BenBarber* found much more relevant references for planar knight moves
in higher dimensions:
"with $n$ even, there is always a knight's tour provided that $n$ is sufficiently large."
*TMA* made an incisive observation that answered my explicit question:
There is no knight's tour for $d=3,4$, due to parity considerations.
So, what remains is: (a) $d \ge 5$ and other odd triangular numbers, or
(b) knight's tours of the even-coordinate-sum ("black") cells in $d=3,4$.

Comment: Some more references on the usual problem: the $n$-dimensional chessboards admitting a (conventional) Knight's tour were classified by [Josh Erde](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5548) and independently by [Bruno and Sylvain Golenia](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5291).

Comment: Note for when the dth triangular number is even (d is 3 or 4 mod 4), the given move does not change parity, so only half the  board can be covered in those dimensions.

Comment: @BenBarber: Thanks, those are much better references for planar knight's moves.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: Astute observation! So the first possibility for a tour occurs in $d=5$.

Comment: It may be of interest to know if there is a black-cell (even coordinates) tour in $d=3$ and $d=4$...

Comment: Even coordinates is one subset...however, the idea of every other cell comes from taking the sum of the coordinates to be even. These are the lattices $D_n.$

Comment: @WillJagy: That's what I meant by "even coordinates," although I now realize how misleading was that phrasing. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: I get it. i thought it was peculiar the way it was, because if you take all coordinates divisible by a common factor, any model of knight move you are considering must have all coordinates divisible by that factor as well, so you just divide through in everything to get back to a primitive problem.

Comment: Note that you can transpose ( as well as alter sign on) two adjacent coordinates to get a move of (1, -1)  on some two dimensional subspace.  This suggests that there is a path which may revisit squares but will eventually visit all squares if there is room to make a move.  I think n  greater than 3d/2 in two dimensions (and similar constraints) will be .enough  to guarantee a tour where possible

Comment: @The Masked Avenger: n must be at least 2d, otherwise there are spaces in the centre that can't be reached/left, since they are less than d distance in some direction from each edge, e.g. (5,5,5,5,5) in the 9^5 board.

Comment: @Joseph, re: black-cell path: the black cells of the 6^3 cube admit a tour, using standard knight's tours of 6x6 boards for the first two coordinates, and hopping between boards in the third coordinate. That is, starting at $(1,1,1)$, use a 2D knight's tour, moving to $(x,y,4)$ for black squares, and back to $(a,b,1)$ for the white squares. Then go on to do 2&5, and 3&6 the same way, getting to those planes by making any move that lands there, and starting at that point in the 6x6 knight's tour.

Comment: I just noticed this might not be closed, so you'll want to make careful choices when jumping between boards. A path from $(1,1,1)$ that ends at $(2,3,4)$ can go to $(5,2,6)$, and then use a path that ends at $(3,1,3)$. From there, go to $(2,4,5)$ and use a path that ends at $(4,3,2)$. So all you need is the existence of $6x6$ tours that include moves $(1,1)\rightarrow(2,3)$, $(5,2)\rightarrow(3,1)$, and $(2,4)\rightarrow(4,3)$.

Comment: I think this can be extended to multiples of $6$ in the 3 dimensional case, and to the 4 dimensional case, with $n=8$, by doing half of the black cells in each pair 1-5, 2-6, etc., then instead of returning to $(1,1,1,1)$, switch the sign of the $1$ or $3$ movement to return to a square with sum $2$ (mod $4$), and do it all over again. It will take some more care to make the path closed.

Comment: @ZackWolske: Very clever to exploit standard knight's tours and then hop between parallel planes/boards!

Answer (score 2):

In my recent preprint, available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.09639), I show that a more natural $d$-dimensional generalization of the planar knight move rule can be deduced from Article 3.6 of Section E of the well-known FIDE hanbook (see [FIDE Handbook](https://handbook.fide.com/)).
Basically, since the aforementioned Article 3.6 refers to the Euclidean distance between the starting cell and the ending cell of a knight jump, we can take as a rule that this Euclidean distance has to be fixed at any jump and it is clearly equal to $\sqrt{5}$ chessboard units. Then, the arising diophantine equation admits only two kinds of solutions for any $d \geq 5$, one describing the well-known L-shaped move (whose taxicab length is $3$) and one changing by one $5$ out of the $d$ Cartesian coordinates of the starting cell.

As a result, by Theorem 4.1, we have that closed (Euclidean) knight's tours esist also on any $2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2 \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^d$ chessboard, as long as $d > 6$ is given.

Theorem 2.1 constructively proves the existence of open Euclidean knight's tours on a $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^5$ chessboard, while there cannot be any closed Euclidean knight's tour on $3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times 3$ chessboards due to the parity argument.

Now, if we still wish to extend the knight move rule by following the pattern $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \dots, \pm d\}$ instead of the more reasonable $\{\pm 2^0, \pm 2^1, \pm 2^2, \dots, \pm 2^d\}$, we should consider that this violates the light-cell/dark-cell rule so that such a knight would jump from a light-cell to another light-cell even on three dimensional chessboard (in 2006, Qing&Watkins clearly explained this fact in their paper entitled [Knigh's Tours for Cubes and Boxes](https://www.math.toronto.edu/yqing/knightstour.pdf), p. 46). Figure 2 of my preprint shows how to properly color a $k$-dimensional chessboard according to the (widely accepted) parity argument and consequently the $1,2,3,\dots,d$ pattern is not coeherent with the light-square/dark-square jumping principle.

I honestly do not thing that this is a minor issue for the given problem and my proposal of considering the $\sqrt{5}$ constraint in order to extend the knight move rule from $d=2$ to $d=3$ and above could open a new perspective on this topic, avoiding to guess the continuation of a short integer sequence as $1, 2, \dots, ?$.

Comment: The FIDE definition says that "The knight may move to one of the squares nearest to that on which it stands but not on the same rank, file or diagonal". How this generalizes to higher dimensions depends on what meaning is then given to "rank, file or diagonal". It seems you have chosen some meaning, but there could be other possibilities. In particular, one could say that a "diagonal" is a direction where any two or more coordinates change by the same amount. Under that interpretation, changing five coordinates by $\pm 1$ would *not* be a knight move.

Comment: As far as I know, it's generally agreed that a diagonal of a $k$-cube is a segment that joins two corners, but if we say so, also every edge should be considered as a diagonal. On the other hand, it seems to me fair obvious that $rank \cup file$ may refer, in $k$-dimensions, to the $k$ orthogonal axes centered in the given vertex. Thus, it wouldn't be very reasonable to assume that the generalized FIDE move rule includes any "diagonal" as the considered set of diagonals, but only the major diagonals. Anyway, a 3D knight cannot move from (1,1,1) to (2,2,1), two of the "nearest" vertices, right?

Comment: In the last sentence of my comment above, I assumed that our $3$D chessboard is described as the set $\{(0,1,2)\times(0,1,2)\times(0,1,2)\}$ of $3^3$ vertices. According to Article 3.6, we would have that the vertices $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ (or $(0,0,1)$ or $(0,2,1)$ and so forth) do not lay on the same file, rank, minor diagonal, major diagonal, or even a Z-axis going from (1,1,0) to (1,1,2), and their distance is only $\sqrt{2}$, so $(2,2,1)$ is one vertex "near" to $(1,1,1)$. Thus, our FIDE knight may be allowed to jump from $(1,1,1)$ to $(2,2,1)$... otherwise it is a Euclidean knight.

Comment: Of course, I meant a Euclidean knight that couldn't be allowed to move along the major diagonal of the given $k$-cube... but the proof of Theorem 4.1 is enough to provide infinitely many closed knight's tours on $n \times n \times \cdots \times n$ chessboards, where $n \in \{2,3\}$